# How to Link struct to the Function?

Tags: c, struct

I don't quite know how the function works together with the concept of structs.
Could somebody explain or show me how it can be done?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct POINT {
    double x;
    double y;
};

double distance_of_points(struct POINT p1, struct POINT p2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((POINT p1), 2) + pow((POINT p2), 2));
};


int main(void)
{
    struct POINT X={1., 1.}, Y={2., 2.}, Z={-2., -1};
    printf("Die Entfernung von X und Y betraegt: %.2f\n", distance_of_points(X, Y) );
    printf("Die Entfernung von X und Z betraegt: %.2f\n", distance_of_points(X, Z) );
    printf("Die Entfernung von Y und Z betraegt: %.2f\n", distance_of_points(Z, Y) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Seems you are doing fine. What's the problem?

Comment: The `;` after `distance_of_points` will not compile. Typo?

Comment: The function doesn't calculate the distance, and im not quiet sure why it isnt

Comment: You know, `POINT` is not a type, `struct POINT` is. That said, `pow((POINT p1)` should better be `pow((p1)...`, most likely.

Comment: 1) `pow` does not take a `POINT` as argument. 2) You cannot pass a type name in a function call: remove the word `POINT`. Turn warnings of your compiler on; a walhala of information will be bestowed upon you.

Comment: Lookup in your math how to calculate the distance between points in a 2d plane.

Comment: Check in the spec which types `pow()` expects. Generally it won't be one you have defined yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
double distance_of_points(struct POINT p1, struct POINT p2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((p1.x - p2.x), 2) + pow((p1.y - p2.y), 2));
};
```

Turn on your compiler warnings!

Comment: Is distance absolute?

Comment: sry, i had them turned on, but I didn't really knew/learned how to use Structs b4 :|
But thanks for the fast reply, now ik how its done!

*(ik what was wrong now^^)  i somehow suspected it had to do with my decleration of the point within the function but i didnt quiet knew what was wrong